# Selection of nested CoreData List SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Im trying to make my List selectable so I can delete or share multiple instances!
Im trying to do that, with this method:
`List(selection: $selection)`
Here's my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@FetchRequest(entity: Rechnungen.entity(), sortDescriptors: [
    NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Rechnungen.datum, ascending: false)
], animation: .default
) var rechnung: FetchedResults<Rechnungen>
   var body: some View {
       //some come where I call:
       ContentListView(rechnung:rechnung)
   }
}
struct ContentListView: View {
@State var selection = Set<Rechnungen>()
var rechnung: FetchedResults<Rechnungen>
   var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selection) {
           ForEach(rechnung) { beleg in
                    //displaying my instances here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I display the EditButton() in my toolbar then I can see the option to select my Instances but I can't select anything.

I guess my `@State var selection = Set<Rechnungen>()`is wrong. But I can't find anything that works.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: `NSManagedObject` doesn't have a UUID property by default. Try `Set<NSManagedObject.ID>` or `Set<NSManagedObjectID>`

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. With ```Set<NSManagedObjectID>()```I least don't get an error but my instances are still not selectable.

Comment: You have left a great deal of code off of here.  What is your `update()` func? Also, `ManagedObjects` conform to `Identifiable` so you don't need (and should avoid at all costs) `id: \.self`. Also, what is the set up of the entity `Rechnungen`? This list looks oddly coded.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I added some code. I hope its more understandable now. update(rechnung) splits my entities into a directionary by month, so I can show them as sections. and also: removing ```id: \.self```just gives me errors or my app crashes.